# In ${\forall}x(P)$, is $P$ any WFF or specifically an open one?

Tags: logic

One of the rules of formation for the language of set theory is

> If $x$ is a variable and $P$ is a ${\square}$, then ${\forall}x(P)$ is a WFF

The reason I wrote ${\square}$ is that I have heard two versions of this rule: that $P$ is any WFF and that $P$ is an open formula.

So which version is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of *well-formed formula* (short: *wff*) for *first-order* language is:

> - every *atomic* formula is a *wff*
> - if $\varphi, \psi$ are *wff*, then $(\lnot \varphi), (\varphi \lor \psi), (\varphi \to \psi), (\varphi \land \psi)$ are *wff*
> - if $\varphi$ is a *wff* and $x_i$ a *variable*, then $(\forall x_i \varphi)$ and $(\exists x_i \varphi)$ are *wff*.

Usual conventions for omitting parentheses are straightforward.

*Note* In order to "apply" a quantifier to a formula $\varphi$, it is not mandatory that the quantified variable is free in $\varphi$. (Of course, quantifying a variable that it is not in the *scope* of the quantifier has no "practical" effects, i.e. it does not affect the "meaning" of the formula.)

---

See :

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA57) (5th ed - 2013), page 57.