# How is constructing new elements described formally

Tags: logic

For example the well formed formulas are formed by some rules. We have an atomic formula which is a formula, a conjunction of two formulas which is also a formula and et cetera.

My question is, how is this set of rules for forming new elements described formally?

Comment: See e.g. thefollowing [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748821/why-%c2%ac%c2%ac-bot-not-in-prop).

Comment: Or this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740870/in-forallxp-is-p-any-wff-or-specifically-an-open-one).

Comment: Also this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876320/is-there-no-propositional-letter-in-first-order-logic).